# combine same of nested dictionaries with different values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a  list of dictionaries with same key but different values like :

```
[{190: {'1': [113, 1, 1551076176, 2, '9', 1]}}, {190: {'2': [113, 1, 1551076176, 3, '13', 1]}}, {190: {'3': [113, 1, 1551076176, 5, '20', 1]}}]
```

What I require is this format :

```
[{190: {'1': [113, 1, 1551076176, 2, '9', 1]},{'2': [113, 1, 1551076176, 3, '13', 1]},{'3': [113, 1, 1551076176, 5, '20', 1]}}]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
OutputObj = {}
InputObj = [{190: {'1': [113, 1, 1551076176, 2, '9', 1]}}, {190: {'2': [113, 1, 1551076176, 3, '13', 1]}}, {190: {'3': [113, 1, 1551076176, 5, '20', 1]}}]
for i in InputObj:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if k in OutputObj:
            OutputObj[k].append(v)
        else:
            OutputObj[k] = [v]
print (OutputObj)
#{190: [{'1': [113, 1, 1551076176, 2, '9', 1]}, {'2': [113, 1, 1551076176, 3, '13', 1]}, {'3': [113, 1, 1551076176, 5, '20', 1]}]}
```

Comment: No description, non-PEP8 spacing and variable names